# lumen- file_get_contents gives error of HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, internal-server-error

In lumen my code is below to send file content in api response , for some document it is working fine but for some document it gives error for HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

```
$content = base64_encode(file_get_contents($URL));
```

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException Object
(
    [statusCode:Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException:private] => 500
    [headers:Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException:private] => Array
        (
        )
```

```
[message:protected] => HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => D:\xampp7.1\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\app\Exceptions\Handler.php
[line:protected] => 76
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    ( ...
```

Is there any solution or required to set php.ini veriable ??

In web error log it gives me error like ,

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version not supported
```

to resolve this I have get file content with help of below,

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $data[$k]['doc_url']);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo"<pre>";print_r($data);die;
```

it gives me empty output without file contect

I have also add below code

`$content = base64_encode(file_get_contents(urlencode($data[$k]['doc_url'])));
                $data[$k]['doc_content'] = "$content";`

It gives me error of , failed to open stream: No such file or directory in PATH...

Comment: Check the web servers error log and see what the error message actually is.

Comment: thanks for reply , for your suggestion I have edited my question,please check this

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the URL your trying to reach is blocking such ways like you've tried to get contents from their server?
Maybe you should use a CURL with all the relevant settings.
The best way I know to duplicate a request is to open developers console on chrome, then on "Newtork" tab find the request that your trying to mimic. Right click -> Copy -> Copy as CURL (cmd), than paste it here to receive the equivalent PHP CURL code:
https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
hope it helps, if not, could you expan on the destination you're trying to reach?

good luck

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set context to this kind of request:

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'protocol_version' => '1.0',
        'method' => 'GET'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
```

Try to get the path to your file like this:

```
$api = "http://PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE?param=optional_query_params";
$response = file_get_contents($api, false, $context);
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer , I have used it ,not solved, I found the issue, Issue was space in url , I have used urlencode, but it not worked, I have replace space with %20 and it worked